# cffunction Access=

Tags: function, coldfusion, constructor

If I use access="remote" for binding a cfselect to a cfc, then I lose the ability to have an Init() constructor.

```
<cfselect name="CityID" bind="cfc:Components.City.View1({StateID})" value="CityID" display="CityName" bindonload="yes" />
```

I'm used to passing the datasource name to the Init function when I instantiate a component, like so:

```
<cfcomponent>
<cffunction name="Init">
<cfargument name="DS">

<cfset Variables.Instance.DS = arguments.DS>
<cfreturn This>
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="View1">
<cfset var qry = "">

<cfquery name="qry" datasource="#Variables.Instance.DS.Datasource#">
SELECT *
FROM Table
</cfquery>
<cfreturn qry>
</cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Phillip, what I usually do in this scenario is:

1. Create the object in onApplicationStart, and store it to the Application scope. This is where you will initialize with your datasource other settings.
2. Create a remote-proxy CFC that is basically a stub for the real thing, and bind your select field to that CFC.

onApplicationStart:

```
<cffunction name="onApplicationStart">
  <cfset application.dsn = "myDSN" />
  <cfset application.cityFinder = createObject("component", "Components.City").init(application.dsn) />
</cffunction>
```

And the remote proxy CFC:

```
<cfcomponent displayName="CityFinderProxy">
  <cffunction name="View1">
    <cfargument name="StateId" />
    <cfreturn application.cityFinder.View1(argumentCollection=arguments) />
  </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Note that I've left out a lot of best-practices (i.e. specifying argument types, required, etc) for brevity... so don't just copy and paste this example. I just wanted to illustrate the idea.

Comment: Adam, what a great reply!  That's is very helpful.  The only problem I have now is that you are using the Application scope inside a cfc.

Comment: Remote proxy objects are a special case. I've yet to come across a better implementation than this. You could use ColdSpring to create these remote proxies, but they will work the same way. http://coldspringframework.org/coldspring/examples/quickstart/index.cfm?page=remote

Comment: Parameterize the storage; use dependency injection to pass the storage mechanism into the CFC, then use the VARIABLES scope from within the CFC itself. Light reading on the ColdSpring framework for DI fundamentals is recommended.

Answer (score 2):

What is the question, exactly?

Setting a CFC to remote is basically making it a web service, so I guess that is why you wouldn't have the init() constructor.

You could easily set the datasource name in an application/session variable that created in the onApplicationStart portion of your application.cfc file.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason why you might not want to create your own remote init function that calls the one you can't reach for you?

Maybe a pain to do it that way.. just food for thought.

Answer (score 1):

What we have done: enacted a software development standard that outlaws any constructor code in our in-house developed components except a single (optional) invocation of the init() method. The so-called constructor code (anything inside the cfcomponent tag that is not inside a cffunction tag) will still get run in when the object is instantiated, and as a result before your method is actually called.

```
<cfcomponent>

  <cfset init() />

  <cffunction name="init">
    <cfset variables.message = "Hello, World" />
    <cfreturn this />
  </cffunction>

  <cffunction name="remoteMethod" access="remote">
    <cfreturn variables.message />
  </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

Comment: This is a good idea, but it doesn't handle passing variables into the constructor.  I've gotten used to passing the datasource into the init to populate variables.instance.datasource.

Comment: You can certainly add optional parameters to your init method - in fact, we prefer to have one optional argument that is a struct we need to pass in parameters, and you can pass in whatever other data you need through that. The only downside is that init will be called twice.